# Finding a pixel position by pixel color

Tags: c++, winapi

The purpose of this function is to find the coordinates of a pixel by a specified pixel color. The function now processes 1/20 from screen resolution, that speed was at least a little tolerable. With this system the accuracy suffers a lot.

```
POINT FindColor(BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b) { 
    HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    int width = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES); 
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES); 
    int xStep = width / 20; 
    int yStep = height / 20; 
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += xStep) { 
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y += yStep) { 
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, x, y); 
            BYTE pixelR = GetRValue(color); 
            BYTE pixelG = GetGValue(color); 
            BYTE pixelB = GetBValue(color); 
            if (pixelR == r && pixelG == g && pixelB == b) { 
                ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
                POINT p;
                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                return p; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC); 
    POINT p = { -1, -1 }; 
    return p; 
}
```

The goal is that every pixel is processed, but finding the color takes more than 1 second.

Probably the best solution will be through a lot of threading, but I have no idea how to formalize it.

The question is, how do I optimize the code so that the code processes all pixels for checking, for accuracy, but the speed of finding the color is ≈ 1 second?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Before posting any questions on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: _every 20 pixels_ You are not doing that. `int xStep = width / 20;` If width is, say, `1920` then `step = 96`. I don't think you want a `yStep` at all because then you are sampling only every `xStep * yStep` pixels.

Comment: You mention threading. Create `n` threads. Have each thread process `height / n` rows. When the pixel is found, kill all threads.

Comment: Creating and destroying threads for each such task would likely make it slower, not faster. You would need to use a thread pool (or C++17 algorithms with execution policy, hoping that your compiler is smart enough).

Comment: A note about 001's comment. Don't literally kill the threads. Send them a message that asks them to politely exit (or abandon the current task if you use a pool like Yksisarvinen suggests). Even if you are very careful in your code, stuff happening in the background outside of your control may not respond well to a thread being killed. Killing threads is a last resort that can be a cure worse than the disease.

Comment: My comment was just a general suggestion. I did a project a while back that was similar (unpacking YUV camera pixels). I was using a thread pool and doing this 30x per sec, but the speed up compared to single threaded was huge.

Comment: iterate y then x might also be more cache friendly...

Comment: In your code, there is a `return` after you call `ReleaseDC`.  The `return` prevents further search of the bitmap.

Comment: [`StretchBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) from `GetDC()` into a memory DC and do a memory search over the bitmap. When doing this, don't compare `BYTE` values. Instead, create a `COLORREF` and search for the full `COLORREF` (though the optimizer probably did this for you already). This still saves a function call with error handling for every pixel.

Comment: I agree with IInspectable. Don't use `GetPixel()` to process individual pixels, that is extremely slow. Copy the screen image into an in-memory bitmap and then process its raw scanlines as needed, that is MUCH faster.

Comment: It's hard to imagine why you're looking for a specific color pixel, you may be suffering from an X-Y problem here.

Comment: I'd agree with Remy Lebeau, with one minor change. If you blit to a normal bitmap, you then have to use GetDIBits to get the raw data into an array where you can look at it so you're doing two copies. Instead, I'd blit to a DIBSection. A DIBSection will let you blit to it, but then let you look at its raw data in place, so you only need to copy once. That said, either should be less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

The following code takes just 58ms to check the entire image (on my 1920 x 1080 screen), no tiling or seperate threads required.

This code could be optimized further, as there is no need to have two for loops for x and y and the index calculated each time, just iterate across the lpPixels array until you find the matching pixel then compute the x and y.

```
HBITMAP GetScreenBmp(HDC hdc) {
    // Get screen dimensions
    int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    // Create compatible DC, create a compatible bitmap and copy the screen using BitBlt()
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL bOK = BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hOld); // always select the previously selected object once done
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    return hBitmap;
}

POINT FindColor(BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b) {
    const COLORREF findColorRef = RGB(r, g, b);

    HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    int width = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = GetScreenBmp(hDC);

    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

    // Get the BITMAPINFO structure from the bitmap
    if (0 == GetDIBits(hDC, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    // create the bitmap buffer
    BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

    // Better do this here - the original bitmap might have BI_BITFILEDS, which makes it
    // necessary to read the color table - you might not want this.
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // get the actual bitmap buffer
    if (0 == GetDIBits(hDC, hBitmap, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID)lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
        cout << "error2" << endl;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {

            if ((lpPixels[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 2] == r) && (lpPixels[4 * ((y * width) + x) + 1] == g) && (lpPixels[4 * ((y * width) + x)] == b)) {

                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                delete[] lpPixels;
                ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
                POINT p;
                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                return p;
            }
        }
    }

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    delete[] lpPixels;
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
    POINT p = { -1, -1 };
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Here's another idea for a benchmark: How long can this code execute before it runs out of system resources? And will it run out of GDI resources or memory first?

Comment: @IInspectable , Thanks leaks fixed, but to answer your question, 43 seconds.